# Meteor not returning data from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

For some reason i can't get data displayed from my Locations collection. No matter what i type i get [object Object] when i write {{myPlaces}} in the HTML. Should i not get a list of the entire content and all fields listed? Can someone explain this, as I get all data from both Meteor.Users and Images. Thank you!

zipCodes.js:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Locations = new Mongo.Collection('locations');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("locations", function () {
   return Locations.find().cursor;
   });
}


if (Meteor.isServer) {

  Locations.batchInsert(
    [
     {
       "country": "NO",
       "zipcode": 1751,
       "place": "Halden",
       "county": "Ostfold",
       "countyNumber": 1,
       "municipality": "Halden",
       "municipalityNumber": 101,
       "lat": 59.1248,
       "long": 11.3875,
       "num": 4
     },
     {
       "country": "NO",
       "zipcode": 1752,
       "place": "Halden",
       "county": "Ostfold",
       "countyNumber": 1,
       "municipality": "Halden",
       "municipalityNumber": 101,
       "lat": 59.1248,
       "long": 11.3875,
       "num": 4
     },
```

testPage.js

```
import './testPage.html';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import Images from '/lib/config/imagesCollection.js';
import { Locations } from '/imports/api/profiles/zipCodes.js';

Template.testPage.helpers({
  // PROFILE INFORMATION
  user: function() {
    return Meteor.users.find();
  },

  // this = {{#each user}} context
  userEmail: function() {
    return this.emails[0].address;
  },

  userFirstName: function() {
    return this.profile.first_name;
  },

  userTitle: function() {
    return this.profile.work_title;
  },

  userMobile: function() {
    return this.profile.mobile;
  },

  userZip: function() {
    return this.profile.zipcode;
  },

  // PATH TO PROFILE PICTURE
  imageLink: function() {
    return Images.findOne({userId: this._id})['_id'];
  },

  // GEODATA TEST
  myPlaces: function() {
    return Locations.find({});
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myPlaces` helper returns a *cursor* - i.e. a function that lets you refer to a list of `Locations`. You need to *iterate* over that cursor to display individual documents using `{{#each }}`. In your html do:

```
<template name="locations">
  {{#each myPlaces}}
    place: {{place}}
    country: {{country}}
    zipcode: {{zipcode}}
   {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: This is all i did in my previous project and i could not remember. Thank you so much! Worked after restarting meteor.